# Compatibility of Serializable and DataContract objects using DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, xml-serialization

I have two classes, one inherits another - base class is DataContract, child is Serializable. I want to move property from child to base class, but after moving it I get exception saying that during deserializing the child class BackingProperty is not found. How can I correctly move that property to base class?

Comment: Did my advice help you?

Comment: @Legart Although your answer was informative, it didn't solve my problem, as I don't want to use just one approach.

Comment: Did it explain you why you can't do that and what you have in result?

Comment: @Legart so you say that it is not possible?

Comment: No, it's not possible with DataContractSerializer. It always enforces order. But when you move property from ChildClass to BaseClass the orders is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the base class decorated with the KnownType attribute?

```
[KnownType(typeof(SuperClass))]
[DataContract]
public class BaseClass
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because serialization for Serializable marked classes and DataContract a bit different.

Here is a serializer I used for the samples:

```
 var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(BaseClass), new List<Type>() { typeof(ChildClass) });
```

You can compare:

```
[DataContract]
public class BaseClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ChildClass: BaseClass
{
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get;set; }
}
```

Xml for that class (using DataContractSerializer, which is standard for WCF ):

```
<BaseClass i:type="ChildClass" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Serialization" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Name>Ivan</Name>
  <_x003C_Age_x003E_k__BackingField>1</_x003C_Age_x003E_k__BackingField>
  <_x003C_SecondName_x003E_k__BackingField>Petrov</_x003C_SecondName_x003E_k__BackingField>
</BaseClass>
```

But when you move a property to base class, which is marked ad DataContract:

```
[DataContract]
public class BaseClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string SecondName { get; set; }

}

[Serializable]
public class ChildClass: BaseClass
{

    public int Age { get;set; }
}
```

Here is xml for that case:

```
<BaseClass i:type="ChildClass" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Serialization" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Name>Ivan</Name>
  <SecondName>Petrov</SecondName>
  <_x003C_Age_x003E_k__BackingField>1</_x003C_Age_x003E_k__BackingField>
</BaseClass>    <BaseClass i:type="ChildClass" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Serialization" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Name>Ivan</Name>
  <SecondName>Petrov</SecondName>
  <_x003C_Age_x003E_k__BackingField>1</_x003C_Age_x003E_k__BackingField>
</BaseClass>
```

As a result you have different element name in Xml (SecondName vs _x003C_SecondName_x003E_k__BackingField) and these two xml are really different.

It's better to use a common approach in you solution, to mark everything or Serializable or DataContract. I would recommend to use DataContract.

**EDIT 1:**

Of course you can try to make a trick with property naming:

```
[DataMember(Name = @"_x003C_SecondName_x003E_k__BackingField", IsRequired = true)]
public string SecondName { get; set; }
```

And XML will be quite the same in result. You can also try to expose feilds for Serializable objects instead of properties:

```
[Serializable]
public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public string SecondName;// { get; set; }
    public int Age; //{get;set;}
}
```

And xml will be:

```
<BaseClass i:type="ChildClass" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Serialization" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Name>Ivan</Name>
  <Age>1</Age>
  <SecondName>Petrov</SecondName>
</BaseClass>
```

But, unfortunately, if you move your property from ChildClass to BaseClass the order of properties will be changed. But DataContractSerializer always enforces the order of elements during deserialization and as a result not all the fields will be deserialzed. But you can switch to use the XmlSerializer in your service, which supports unordered deserialization.

**Finally: Marking all data contract with DataContract**

Even if you mark both your classes with DataContract, DataMember:

```
[DataContract]
public class BaseClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    //[DataMember]
    //public string SecondName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

And then move a property from ChildClass to BaseClass, it will still not work. Your property will be null (or default value), as the order has been changed :(